# How to programmatically bind XML file as Telerik Reporting datasource?

Tags: c#, xml, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I want to bind a XML file as datasource of Telerik reportViewer.
I tried this code but not working:

```
DataSet rptDataSet = new DataSet();
rptDataSet.ReadXml(//filepath);
var objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource();                       
var report = new Telerik.Reporting.Report();
var reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();

objectDataSource.DataSource = rptDataSet;                        
report.DataSource = objectDataSource;
reportSource.ReportDocument = report;
reportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: "not working" is not a really descirption of an error. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: There's [Telerik FAQ about XML loading](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/faq-xml-support#does-telerik-reporting-support-xml-as-a-datasource).

Comment: @TobiasTheel Not any error occured.It just results empty report.

Comment: @Reniuz Thank you,but if you look at my code, i do the same

Comment: Have you tried to add ObjectDataSource component with wizard? Have you checked the generated code then? Aren't there more things done with ObjectDataSource before setting it to report.DataSource?

Comment: @TobiasTheel, with report some time it is the only possible description. Telerik report now cache and pre process some of the item. Even adding code in the report constructor is deprecated. Make a report with just a boolean printed in a text box. In debug Parameter will be always good. in prod sometimes, the report will ignore the paramter and use an old cached one. To do this you just have to deploy 1rst a version with the paramater but not use it then deploy a version that use it. and magic happend.

Comment: Most of the process is throught the gui, even if designer code can be copy past, it's hard to isolate everything in those wysiwyg report

Comment: @Reniuz Yes, also i did [this solution](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/bind-your-telerik-reports-to-xml-data) and unfortunately give me an error "it is not allowed to add table"

Comment: @DragandDrop I don't understand clearly; How can i do it?What's better if I saw a sample...